# ASP.NET AJAX Tab Container

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need a tab-like control for Asp website. This is a tutorial for AJAX Control Toolkit Tab Container. The code below is debugged successfully, but nothing is shown on browser. Please explain.

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
            Width="600">
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                   Tab Panel One
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="140px" ImageUrl="~/dg1.gif" 
                        Width="138px" />
                    Tab Panel1
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                  Tab Panel Two
                 </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Items</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Items</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Items</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Itens</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Items</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem>Items</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="89px" ImageUrl="~/dg2.gif" 
                        Width="122px" />
                    Tab Panel2
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                  Tab Panel Three
                 </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="151px" ImageUrl="~/dg3.gif" 
                        Width="106px" />
                    Tab panel 3
                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
       </cc1:TabContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a `scripmanager` on the page and a `<%@ Register` for the ajax control toolkit on your page?
Your code works fine for me.